# Coreutils realpath: confusing output when used with a hard (?) link

Tags: coreutils

I was "playing around" and messed up my install of pip (Python package manager). Anyhow, it turns out, in my system `/bin/pip` is (?) a hard link of `/usr/bin/pip` (or the other way around, since I'm told with hard links there is no notion of which file is the original).

```
$ realpath /bin/pip /usr/bin/pip
/usr/bin/pip
/usr/bin/pip
```

The results of `realpath` have me confused. If there is no notion of which file is the original, why does `realpath` display `/usr/bin/pip` instead of `/bin/pip` for `/bin/pip`?

I know either may be a hard link because:

```
$ stat -c "%n is a %F pointing to inode %i, which has %h hard link(s)" /bin/pip /usr/bin/pip
/bin/pip is a regular file pointing to inode 152837, which has 1 hard link(s)
/usr/bin/pip is a regular file pointing to inode 152837, which has 1 hard link(s)
```

Just in case, my machine is running CentOS 7 and my realpath command comes from GNU coreutils 8.22.

-------- EDIT -------

Indeed, /bin is a symlink pointing to /usr/bin, while /usr/bin is a regular directory:

```
$ ls -ld /bin /usr/bin
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     7 May 15 12:49 /bin -> usr/bin
dr-xr-xr-x. 2 root root 53248 Jul 13 18:44 /usr/bin
```

Comment: That is because ``/bin`` is symlink to ``/usr/bin``

Comment: Every ordinary file has (or is) one hard link.  If `/bin/pip` and `/usr/bin/pip` were hardlinks to the same diskfile, it would show as `2 hard link(s)` for each in your output.

Comment: No, every ordinary _directory_ entry is one hard link. Files are not links, they are files.

Comment: I've updated the question. Indeed, /bin is a symlink, so what does that make of the files under /bin?

Comment: If `/bin` is a symlink, then the files under `/bin` are actually in `/usr/bin`!  If you do `ls -l /bin /usr/bin` you should get two identical sets of output. The files all exist in the same directory - `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested this, and it doesn't happen for me. I would suspect (as suggested) that it's due to a symbolic link somewhere, since `realpath` resolves those.

Try:

```
ls -li /bin/pip /usr/bin/pip
```

That should double check that the two directory entries reference the same inode/file (either directly or indirectly).

Now try:

```
ls -ld /bin /usr/bin
```

That should show two directories (`d` in the first column). If one of them (almost certainly `/usr/bin` shows an `l` in that column, then it's a symbolic link, and that would explain the behaviour you are seeing (as noted earlier, `realpath` resolves symbolic links).

Final clarification: if one of `/bin` or `/usr/bin` is a symbolic link to the other, the `realpath` will follow the symlink  to its target, and it'll use that target as the real path.

GNU `realpath` (but not all others) has the `--no-symlinks` option; if you use that, you'll probably get the result you originally expected.

Comment: I just tested on Ubuntu, /bin isn't a symlink there!

Comment: I don't think there are many systems where it _is_ a symlink!